# Dart - Using Mixins vs Dependency Injection

Tags: flutter, dart

Is there a difference (in terms of good design) when using mixins vs dependency injection?

I'm relatively new to Dart, and this is the first time I learned about mixins.

Using mixin:

```dart
mixin Foo {
  bar() => print('Bar!');
}

class MyClass with Foo {
  doBar() => bar();
}
```

Using DI:

```dart
abstract class FooService {
  bar();
}

class FooServiceImpl implements FooService {
  @override
  bar() => print('Bar!');
}

class MyClass {
  MyClass(this.fooService);

  final FooService fooService;

  doBar() => fooService.bar();
}
```

Comment: I am wondering if you found out the answer your self.